# K & R malloc code doesn't make sense?

Tags: c, malloc, kernighan-and-ritchie

This code is from the K & R book - Chapter 8 Section 7: Example - Storage Allocator. This code, at least for me, doesn't make sense. "Header" is a union of a struct and a "most restrictive alignment type", which is a long type. Malloc will then find a big enough free space with size of a multiple of the header size.

```
static Header base;            /* empty list to get started */
static Header *freep = NULL;   /* start of free list */

/* malloc: general-purpose storage allocator */
void *malloc(unsigned nbytes)
{
  Header *p, *prevp;
  Header *morecore(unsigned);
  unsigned nunits;
  nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(Header) + 1;
  if ((prevp = freep) == NULL) {     /* no free list yet */
    base.s.ptr = freeptr = prevptr = &base;
    base.s.size = 0;
  }
  for (p = prevp->s.ptr; ; prevp = p, p = p->s.ptr) {
    if (p->s.size >= nunits) { /* big enough */
      if (p->s.size == nunits) /* exactly */
        prevp->s.ptr = p->s.ptr;
      else {     /* allocate tail end */
        p->s.size -= nunits;
        p += p->s.size;
        p->s.size = nunits;
      }
      freep = prevp;
      return (void *)(p+1);
    }
    if (p == freep) /* wrapped around free list */
      if ((p = morecore(nunits)) == NULL)
        return NULL; /* none left */

  }
}
```

The odd part of this code is the statement `nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(Header) + 1;` which is then used in the comparison `if (p->s.size >= nunits)` to find a big enough space with units in terms of the size of Header. Shouldn't the former be `nunits = (nbytes+sizeof(Header)) / sizeof(Header)` only? The original code would evaluate to a value less than it ought to be.  What is with the +-1s? Why allocate space less than the desired.

Comment: Keep operator precedence in mind, and analyze that again...

Comment: @duffymo: Instead of telling me that, can't you just tell me how the code works? By the way, have you read that book? Noticed the lots of typos? But no one said anything about those.

Comment: Assume this is the first call to `malloc` and you have requested 1 byte i.e. `malloc(1)` and see what `nunits` returns with both your suggested fix and the code in the book.

Comment: @K-ballo: Of couse, how stupid of me. But there is another confusion. That code would evaluate to a larger size for big allocations. Why not just do the arithmetic without the 1s?

Comment: Yeah, I've read the book.  You're the one reading it for the first time, not me.  Spend some time thinking about the idiom.

Comment: @dirkgently: now that makes sense

Comment: K&R is not a "learn to program" book. Its intended audience is *programmers* and as such the authors feel free to treat you like a grown-up. They don't "tell you how it works" because they assume that knowing the pieces that went into it you can figure it out for yourself. If you find yourself confused by something in there you probably haven't thought carefully enough about it. Go back, read that part again and consider *exactly* what is being said.

Comment: @dmckee: well said. I'll remember that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-1` and `+1` are to account for values that aren't multiplies of the block size.

For example, suppose the block size is 10. If you try to use the formula `n / 10` to get the number of required blocks then you would get 1 block for n = 15. This is wrong, you need 2.

If you change the formula to be `n / 10 + 1` then it will also be wrong. When n = 20 you only need 2 blocks, but that formula will return 3.

The correct formula is `(n - 1) / 10 + 1`. That's how you round up with integer division. The only difference with this and the formula you asked about is the extra `sizeof(Header)`, which is just the extra space needed for the header itself.

Comment: Thanks this really helps. Actually the confusion resulted from the fact that I considered the expression after the division sign '/' as a whole unit.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `(n + 9) / 10`?

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: Yep, that's what I usually use.

Comment: They probably ported it from assembler :-)

Answer (score 3):

`(nbytes+sizeof(Header)-1)/sizeof(Header) + 1` is a pretty standard idiom in code to get the number of units of something with the correct rounding up. It you try it with some values you will see that it works correctly.

The actual idiom is better expressed as `(nbytes - 1)/unitSizeInBytes + 1`.

To clarify, based on the last paragraph of the accepted answer the use of `sizeof(Header)` is different on both sides of the division. It's use in the dividend is because it needs to allocate bytes for the Header and nbytes. It's use in the divisor is because that's the size of the blocks being allocated. It happens in this case that they are the same value, `sizeof(Header)`.

Comment: Yes, and as K-ballo says, consider operator precedence.

Comment: Does this imply that I should read others' codes a lot in order to get familiar with these standard idioms?

Comment: Yes it does, and asking questions like this is also a good idea, but study carefully before you do. Read good open source code. Then work on it. Make the world better. :)

Comment: @1der: You'll also happen upon these kinds of things just by writing lots of code. At some point, you'll need to solve the same problem, and you'll probably come up with the same solution, and learn to recognise it.

Comment: I understand the expression in the division as that just gets the ceiling of `nbytes` / `sizeof(Header)`.  What's the `+ 1` for?

Comment: To account for what would be the remainder to round up to the next value. If you did not have it and the division was not even then you would not allocate a unit for the remainder.

Comment: Doesn't `(nbytes + sizeof(Header) - 1)/sizeof(Header)` automatically account for the remainder?  I think that that expression always gives the ceiling of the division and hence the `+ 1` is unnecessary and causes the above code to allocate one more unit than is needed.

Comment: Have alook at the revision of my comments and the accepted answer.

Comment: Ah, we need enough space for `nbytes` (in units of `sizeof(Header)`) along with enough space to store a `Header`.  Thanks for clarifying.